# Wordpress pagination with custom posts_per_page issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

In a custom Woocommerce products page I filter posts_per_page with a dropdown menu. It works well and the table is updated with the new value.
But then if I click on the 'Next' button, next_posts_link doesn't post the new posts_per_page value, and the second page starts from record #11, as default.
Any solution?

```
<?php                   
       $prodNum = $_POST['num_prods'];
?>

<!-- SELECT POST PER PAGES  -->
<form id="numProdsForm" method="POST">
    <select name="num_prods" id="num_prods" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="10" <?php if ($prodNum==10){ ?> selected <?php }  ?>>10</option>
      <option value="20" <?php if ($prodNum==20){ ?> selected <?php }  ?>>20</option>
      <option value="30" <?php if ($prodNum==30){ ?> selected <?php }  ?>>30</option>
      <option value="50" <?php if ($prodNum==40){ ?> selected <?php }  ?>>50</option>
      <option value="100" <?php if ($prodNum==50){ ?> selected <?php }  ?>>100</option>
    </select>
</form>


<!-- CUSTOM TABLE  -->

<table>
<?php if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) { ?>

    
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $prodNum,
            'orderby'=>'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $product;
    ?>

            <tr>
                <td class="flex-row" role="cell"><?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'color' ); ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php
    } else {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
    }
    ?>

</table>

<div class="products-pagination">
<?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?>
<?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?>
</div>
```

I've tried to put the pagination before wp_reset_query();, or to use get $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you try to add $paged before you declared $args and then pass $paged inside your args array like 'paged' => $paged

Comment: yes, I tried it without success:
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $prodNum,
            'orderby'=>'title',
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'paged' => $paged
        );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a "GET" rather than "POST" for the form, and pass the offset and number of posts to show as URL params.  Then you can add the `offset` attribute to the query.  You can also optimize some of your code by using `selected` [selected function definition](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/) rather than your if statements for the options.

```
<?php
$product_number  = ( isset( $_GET['num_prods'] ) ) ? absint( $_GET['num_prods'] ) : 0;
$existing_offset = ( isset( $_GET['offset'] ) ) ? absint( $_GET['offset'] ) : 0;
$offset          = $product_number + $existing_offset;
?>
    <!-- SELECT POST PER PAGES  -->
    <form id="numProdsForm" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $offset ); ?>">
        <select name="num_prods" id="num_prods" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value=""> - - Choose Number of Products to Show -- </option>
            <option value="10" <?php selected( 10, $product_number ); ?>>10</option>
            <option value="20" <?php selected( 20, $product_number ); ?>>20</option>
            <option value="30" <?php selected( 30, $product_number ); ?>>30</option>
            <option value="50" <?php selected( 50, $product_number ); ?>>50</option>
            <option value="100" <?php selected( 100, $product_number ); ?>>100</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <!-- CUSTOM TABLE  -->
    <table>
        <?php if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) { ?>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => $product_number,
                'offset'         => $offset, // the offset.
                'orderby'        => 'title',
                'order'          => 'ASC',
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                $loop->the_post();
                global $product;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="flex-row" role="cell"><?php echo $product->get_attribute( 'color' ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // use wp_reset_postdata(). ?>
            <?php
        } else {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <div class="products-pagination">
        <?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages ); ?>
        <?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </div>
```